# Unable to access Graph API when using Microsoft App Developer API key

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm still not able to access the Graph API when using my developer API key from the [Microsoft App Registration Portal](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/) (Azure AD v2.0 endpoint) as the "[client_secret](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview)" and I receive the following error message when using the below URL in my web browser to test manually:

Error message:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Bearer access token is empty.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "902fec23-3ac7-433a-952c-4b0c4213869",
      "date": "2018-06-05T15:23:11"
    }
  }
}
```

URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/<tenant_name>.sharepoint.com/_api/web/lists?client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&client_secret=xxXXxxxxxxxxx
```

I'm trying to do test this without authenticating with my O365 account as this will go into a script to perform callouts to Sharepoint Online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Microsoft Graph without authenticating. Every call to the Graph must include a valid access token in the `Authorization` header:

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview):

> To call Microsoft Graph, your app must acquire an access token from Azure Active Directory (Azure AD), Microsoft's cloud identity service. The access token contains information (or claims) about your app and the permissions it has for the resources and APIs available through Microsoft Graph. To get an access token, your app must be able to authenticate with Azure AD and be authorized by either a user or an administrator for access to the Microsoft Graph resources it needs.

Comment: Marc, how would I be able to generate an access token if I have a developer API key? I tried: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx&scope=files.read.all&client_secret=xxxxxxXXxxxxx where the client secret is my API key and that fails.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "developer API key"? I've never heard that phrase used in reference to Microsoft Graph or AAD

Comment: Sure. If you log into https://apps.dev.microsoft.com, select "Add an App", complete the info, and under Application Secrets, select "Generate New Password", it'll give you a one-time key to programmatically access the O365 environment.

Comment: That isn't what you think it is. That is the "Client Secret" that you use to obtain your token from the `/token` endpoint. It is part of the OAuth flow. This article might help: https://massivescale.com/microsoft-v2-endpoint-primer/

Comment: Hi Marc, that definitely helped, thanks! Just one last question, once I have the access token, how would I use it in a web browser to access the resources I want to get? I didn't come across a property name in the article that discusses using one.

Comment: You add it to the `Authorization` header as `Bearer {access_token}` (space between Bearer and the token is intentional and required.

Comment: Got it. Thanks again Mark!